# CommandError: The permission codename 'change_mymodel' clashes with a builtin permission for model 'myapp.MyModel'

Tags: django, django-south

I upgrade my application from django1.3 to django1.5, and get this error:

```
CommandError: The permission codename 'change_mymodel' clashes with a builtin permission  for model 'myapp.MyModel'
```

Related commit https://github.com/django/django/commit/8c427448d53ec0d860e1669f35deed73d0240ba1

Related ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15915

The code works well with django1.3.

**Update**

This question is old, and I have not since several months. The ticket is fixed since four years ...

Answer (score 5):

Did you define custom permissions with names staring with "add_", "change_" or "delete_"?

If yes, then these permissions clash with the default permissions as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions).

In this case:
Remove your custom permissions and use the default ones or rename your custom permissions so they don't clash with the default ones.

Comment: I updated tthe question. This question is old, and I have not since several months. The ticket is fixed since four years ...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself

```
def _check_permission_clashing(custom, builtin, ctype):
    pass

class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        ...
        from django.contrib.auth import management
        management._check_permission_clashing=_check_permission_clashing
```

Not nice, but works.